# Observer pattern falling short when subscribers need subclasses of main message type, alternatives?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am having issues designing a clean solution for sending messages of different types using an observer pattern style solution.

I have a client application connecting to a server (that I cannot change) over a tcp socket. I can send and receive json encoded messages which will always contain a "msg" parameter which defines what type of message it is. Also note that I can recieve messages that are sent to several clients and weren't requested by my own client (if someone sends a chat message, for example).

Example:
On connect I receive `{"msg":"ServerInfo","version":"1.0a"}`

Sending `{"msg":"Ping"}` replies with `{"msg":"Ping","time":1381358623}`

I could receive `{"msg":"Chat", "from":"Person", "text":"Hello everyone"}` at any time

Some of the messages are more complex and can have nested objects, for example

```
{
    "msg":"SampleData",
    "people":[{
        "name":"Joe"
        "age":25
    },{
        "name":"Bob",
        "age":30
    }]
}
```

There are a couple dozen different types of messages all with varying amounts and types of fields.

I currently have a class which is responsible for listening on the socket and parsing all messages using Gson in to a "BasicMessage" class which only has the "msg" parameter. I have a Map mapping all the message type strings to their respective classes. Once I have the "msg" paremeter I can lookup the class I need to deserialize it to with Gson and then do so. Now I have an instance of the correct class but this is where my design starts falling apart.

I would like to have various other classes have the ability to subscribe to only a few types of messages. The issue is I can't seem to find a way that does this without requiring either a bunch of instanceof's or reparsing everything again in every client.

My initial thought was to use a parameterized interface like so:

```
public interface MessageListener<T> {
    public void onReceivedMessage(T message);
}
```

then in the class that deserializes the messages, I had a `List<MessageListener<Message>>` where Message was the abstract class every other Message inherited from. Then I ran in to the type erasure issue where `MessageListener<SpecificMessage>` doesn't inherit from `MessageListener<Message>` so I didn't have a way I could add the clients to one simple list. It seemed as though I would have to have a list for each type of message which is also not ideal. Another issue with this design is it would limit me to only using anonymous inner classes for the various message listeners in a class that would need more than one since you also can't implement the same interface twice even if you parameterize it with a different class.

Is there a better pattern that I could be using for this situation? I feel like I might have to use reflection to get this to work "neatly". Ideally, if I want to add another message type I would like it to require simply adding the class for it to deserialize to and perhaps a mapping from its msg string to that class and then be able to start adding listeners for that type of message in another class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an alternative design, but [Guava's event bus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) seems to be a good fit for your problem.

Comment: @Pyranja I like the looks of the EventBus. I'll try it out.

Comment: @Pyranja EventBus is working perfectly. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [guava eventbus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) offers a publish/subscribe messaging component, designed to simplify  the implemenation of the classic *Observer* pattern. Instead of having to explicitly register dedicated `Listener` or [`Observer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) instances with an event emitting object, one registers a class, which is interested in certain events with the bus:

```
class MyEventListeningClass {
   @Subscribe public void onEvent(MyEvent e) {
      // react to event
   }
}
...
eventBus.register(new MyEventListeningClass());
```

Registration and dispatching of events to interested subscribers is done through reflection.

As seen already in the question and other answers, Java's type system makes it hard to achieve a similar flexibility with listener interfaces. For the use case in question, the event bus seems to be a good fit, especially when more message types need to be added in the future. Alas the usual caveats of such loose coupling apply: it is harder to reason about, what exactly will happen with a message.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a list, how about storing a `HashMap<Class<? extends Message>, List<MessageListener<? extends Message>>`? That buys you a simpler lookup when a message comes in and you have an indeterminate number of listeners interested in an indeterminate number of events. Just look up the list of listeners interested in your deserialized message type. You'd set it up so that you could only add to the map in a way that provides you compile-time checking:

```
public <T> void addListener(Class<T>, MessageListener<T>) {...}
```

Also, you're not limited to using *anonymous* inner classes when you implement these listeners, only *inner* classes. It might make your classes a little longer, but it helps greatly during debugging if you just line them up at the bottom of each class that needs them like so:

```
private class SampleDataListener implements MessageListener<SampleData> {
    ...
    public void messageReceived(SampleData message) {...}
}

private class OtherDataListener implements MessageListener<OtherData> {
    ...
    public void messageReceived(OtherData message) {...}
}
```

Comment: I like this approach but I went with Guava's EventBus.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility (but note that I haven't tested it).  Unfortunately, it will require a certain method to be added to every subclass of `BasicMessage`; I've tried to make it as short as possible to limit the duplication.  In each class `SpecificMessage`, add this:

```
public static void addListener (SocketListener s, MessageListener<SpecificMessage>               listener)
{
    s.addSubclassListener (SpecificMessage.class, listener);
}
```

I'm assuming `SocketListener` is the class that would be listening to the socket and later sending messages to the subscribers.  (You can change it to whatever's appropriate.)

In `SocketListener`:

```
private interface BasicMessageListener {
    public void onReceivedMessage (BasicMessage message);
}

protected <T extends BasicMessage> void addSubclassListener (final Class<?> clazz, final MessageListener<T> listener)
{
    addBasicMessageListener (clazz, new BasicMessageListener () {
        public void onReceivedMessage (BasicMessage message) {
            if (message.getClass() != clazz)
                throw new ClassCastException ();
            listener.onReceivedMessage ((T) message);
        }
    }
}
```

`addBasicMessageListener` will be the method that registers a listener for the class.  Since its parameter isn't generic, you should be able to add it to a list.  (Note: the typecast to `(T)` will give you unchecked warnings.)  The idea is that if other classes want to register a listener to listen to messages of class `SpecificMessageXYZ`, they'd use

```
SpecificMessageXYZ.addListener (theSocketListener, new MessageListener<SpecificMessageXYZ> () {
    ...
    ... a listener that takes a SpecificMessageXYZ parameter
    ...
});
```

or something to that effect.  This still will involve a downcast, but it will be only in one place (in `addSubclassListener`), rather than having to do an `instanceof` and downcast in every listener that the other classes may want to register.  Whether that's enough of a gain to make up for having to put the duplicated method in every message class, I don't know.  However, I can't think of another way without using reflection.  I think what you're looking for is some interesting sort of covariance that doesn't exist in Java.

Again, I'll warn you that I haven't actually tried this, except that I ran it through the compiler to make sure I wasn't doing anything illegal.  Also please note that my choice of method/class names tends to be lousy.

EDIT: It occurred to me that although `(T) message` isn't able to perform a check, we already have the information needed to do the check, so we should.